# What is the basic structure required to create a custom database driver?

Tags: 7, database

I need to create a custom database driver, and the [documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/310087) was never completed.

Can someone provide a list of the classes that need to be implemented to realise this, and a brief description of what each should contain?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request for tutorials/links to offsite resources.

Comment: Hi @Clive maybe the my english was not the best when I said I was looking for any tutorials or resources. The reality is that there is not information available about how to write a database driver for Drupal. Maybe someone from the site will step in and shine a light on the subject.

Comment: It's just not the right sort of thing for Q+A (in its current form) - the general of thumb is that if you can imagine an entire book/tutorial/blog post being required to answer a question, it's going to be too broad for a Stack Exchange site. Specific questions about problems you're facing while implementing a driver would be fine, welcomed with open arms even, but as it stands there are just too many possible ways of answering this question for it to fit into the format here. Ask yourself "what _specifically_ do I need to know to get to the next step", then ask a question here, then repeat

Comment: I can not reach that point, because there are no starting points, no documentation, etc. So, the question should be how or what should I do to start writing a database driver for Drupal 7.

Comment: I've edited it to make it a bit more narrow, look ok? It'd be useful if you could edit in what you already know (e.g. have you looked at existing core and contrib drivers like the Oracle driver? What did you learn from those? Anything in particular you didn't understand?) That'll hopefully give you more specific follow-up questions to ask, "how do I register my custom driver?" would be a separate question, and so on